# Hide/Show Data Labels on update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to use

```
data: {
  labels: true
}
```

in a standard chart, as shown here: http://c3js.org/samples/data_label.html

It is very fine when I use `c3.generate` function to create a new chart.

Now that the chart is created, I would like to **hide/show** these labels on `update` (when I load new data). I don't find how to properly do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in way to toggle data labels.
But you can control its visibility using *d3.js* (which *c3.js* is based on):

```
d3.select('.c3-chart-texts').style('display', 'none') // or 'block'
```

---

*UPDATE:*

If you got multiple charts, you can select corresponding labels either **by chart object**:

```
chart1.internal.selectChart.select('.c3-chart-texts')...
```

or **by chart id**:

```
d3.select('#chart1').select('.c3-chart-texts')...
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused because I begin with D3...
Let's say I have 2 charts (`chart1` and `chart2`), how can I only select `chart1`? Thanks

Comment: No problem, see update! Both variants result the same.